# SystemVerilog task that can force any signal in interface module

Tags: system-verilog

```
interface dut_if();
    logic       sig_a_i;
    logic [1:0] sig_b_i;
endinterface

module tb();
    dut_top dut(
        .sig_a_i  (vif.sig_a_i);
        .sig_b_i  (vif.sig_b_i);
    );

    dut_if vif();
endmodule
```

How to create a `task()` method inside the `interface` class such that I can easily call it within my `test` class to `force`/`release` any DUT signal I like?

```
class dut_testA_vseq extends dut_base_vseq;
    ...

    virtual task body();
        p_sequencer.vif.force_dut_signal(0);
    endtask
endclass
```

I'm new to SV and I don't know how to write `force_dut_signal()` that can cater to any signal (single bit or a bus).

```
task force_dut_signal(logic? port_name, bit? force_val) begin
    force port_name? = force_val;
endtask
```

The `?` in the code snippet above are parts I don't know if possible or what.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `?` is illegal there. I guess it was cut and paste issue. `force_dut_signal` is probably a function, defined within the interface which you are missing.

Comment: @Serge, if you read the description carefully, I intentionally added the `?` beside those SV constructs which I am not sure if correct or even possible. Please upvote the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in SystemVerilog that allows you to pass a hierarchical reference to a signal as a reference to a task/function argument. Inside your interface, you will need to create a function for each signal or group of signals you need to force. Then call that function from class.

BTW, always use functions instead of tasks for non-time-consuming procedures.

Comment: is there a way to do this as macro in case I need to force many signals?

Comment: @dave_59, now might be a good time to push your paper: https://s3.amazonaws.com/verificationacademy-news/DVCon2016/Posters/dvcon-2016_introspection-into-systemverilog-without-turning-it-inside-out_poster_paper.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a signal by reference into your task. However the data types must match and you can't use a fork, join_any, join_none inside your task. This works for sig_a_i only:

```
interface dut_if();
  logic       sig_a_i;
  logic [1:0] sig_b_i;
endinterface

module dut_top(
  input logic sig_a_i, 
  input logic [1:0] sig_b_i);
endmodule

module tb();
  dut_top dut(
      .sig_a_i  (vif.sig_a_i),
      .sig_b_i  (vif.sig_b_i)
  );

  dut_if vif();

  function automatic force_1bit_logic(ref logic signal, input bit value);
      signal = value;
  endfunction    

  initial begin
      #1;
      force_1bit_logic(vif.sig_a_i, 0);
      #10;
      force_1bit_logic(vif.sig_a_i, 1);
  end
endmodule
```